# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{x\cos(x)}{x^2+1}$ via contour integration.

Tags: complex-analysis

As in the title, I want to compute $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{x\cos(x)}{x^2+1}$. Normally, if the $x$ in the numerator weren't there, I'd do the standard $f(z) = e^{iz}/(z^2+1)$, then use the upper semicircle contour and then turn then, etc. and then take the real part after parametrizing the real line and then taking 1/2 the real part to get the answer.

If I try that with this integral, though, $f(z) = ze^{iz}/(z^2+1)$, the above strategy ends up cancelling the real part and I'm left with $2i\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+1} = 2\pi i \text{Res}_i f$. To be more explicit, when parametrizing the real line $\gamma(t) = t$, $-R\le t \le R$, some large $R$, then
$$
\int_{-R}^R \frac{te^{it}}{t^2+1} = \int_{0}^R \frac{te^{it}}{t^2+1} - \int_{0}^{-R} \frac{te^{it}}{t^2+1} = \int_{0}^R \frac{te^{it}}{t^2+1} - \int_{0}^{R} \frac{ye^{-iy}}{y^2+1} = 2i\int_{0}^R \frac{t\sin(t)}{t^2+1},
$$
which is not the integral I want. Should be I using a different $f(z)$ or perhaps a different contour? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, don't go into the left half-plane. Do a contour just (mostly) in the right half-plane!

Comment: @TedShifrin what do you mean ?

Comment: @TedShifrin I assume you mean going along a sector with a tiny semicircle around the pole at $i$? I'll give it a try.

Comment: My apology. I didn't pay enough attention. Your original contour was right, although there is subtlety on the estimate on the large semicircle. You were sloppy because you left out $dz$ and $dt$. Get over that in a hurry!

Comment: @TedShifrin hmm, so are you saying that part of the integral over the large semicircle will not go to 0? I feel like that's not the case. And I apologize for sloppiness, but I was hoping it was clear that my integrals above were with respect to the variables that appear in the integrand.

Comment: Because of your missing $dt$’s, you got totally the wrong result. But the usual estimate for the semicircle will not show it goes to $0$. You should look at the usual discussion of estimates of $e{iz}/z$ on the semicircle.

Comment: I found my mistake : $f(z+i \pi) = e^{-i\pi a} f(z)$, so my contour doesn't work, and I don't get why

Comment: @TedShifrin Redoing it, I see that the way I originally estimated it didn't work as you said, but I will say it was due to a calculus mistake, not the lack of $dt$'s as I included them in my scratch work, just not in this post. In any case, if I'm going to consider $e^{iz}/z$, wouldn't that mean I need to consider a different $f(z)$? Or perhaps it shows up in dividing every term by $z^2$.

Comment: The estimate for $ze^{iz}/(z^2+1)$ will be exactly like that for $e^{iz}/z$ on a large semicircle. Your lack of $dt$'s made even symmetry disappear when you broke up the integral.

Comment: Anyway your integral doesn't have a closed-form, [see WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*Cos%5Bx%5D%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)++dx+for+x+%3D+0+to+Infinity) $I = -(Ei(-1)+Ei(1))e/2$ where $Ei$ is the exponential integral

Comment: @user1952009 Ah okay, that's no fun. This was on an old qualifying exam which I was using to study for. Perhaps they asked it by mistake, since doing the integral with $sin$ in place of $cos$ is much easier. In any case, I'll give this one a rest for now then and do some other problems.

Comment: What does a closed form have to do with the integral from $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @TedShifrin A contour integral that doesn't involve an infinity of poles has a closed-form